# connect webpage through web socket to MQTT broker

Tags: javascript, websocket, mqtt, iot, paho

i created mqtt broker at cloudMQTT and here is the info about ports & server that i got

[image: click to see image of ports]

now i wrote that code to run web page that connect to that broker and send hello world.

```
<html>
   <head>
      <title>JavaScript MQTT WebSocket Example</title>
      <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/paho-mqtt/1.0.1/mqttws31.js" type="text/javascript">
     </script>
     <script type = "text/javascript" language = "javascript">
        var mqtt;
        var reconnectTimeout = 2000;
        var host="m23.cloudmqtt.com"; //change this
        var port= 38788;

        function onConnect() {
      // Once a connection has been made, make a subscription and send a message.

        console.log("Connected ");
        //mqtt.subscribe("sensor1");
        message = new Paho.MQTT.Message("Hello world");
        message.destinationName = "orange1";
        mqtt.send(message);
      }
      function MQTTconnect() {
        console.log("connecting to "+ host +" "+ port);
        mqtt = new Paho.MQTT.Client(host,port,"clientjs");
        //document.write("connecting to "+ host);
        var options = {
            timeout: 3,
            onSuccess: onConnect,

         };

        mqtt.connect(options); //connect
        }

      </script>
   </head>
     <body>
   <h1>Main Body</h1>
    <script>
    MQTTconnect();
    </script>
   </body>
</html>
```

every time i open that page and open console.js i got that problem message:

[image: error message that appear at console.log]

(here are list of errors that appears at my console.log .. to help anyone who can see images)
WebSocket connection to 'ws://m23.cloudmqtt.com:38788/mqtt' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET mqttws31.js:979

Paho.MQTT.ClientImpl._doConnect @ mqttws31.js:979

Paho.MQTT.ClientImpl.connect @ mqttws31.js:849

Client.connect @ mqttws31.js:1799

MQTTconnect @ websockets-1.htm:31

(anonymous) @ websockets-1.htm:39

WebSocket connection to 'ws://m23.cloudmqtt.com:38788/mqtt' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET mqttws31.js:977

Paho.MQTT.ClientImpl._doConnect @ mqttws31.js:977

Paho.MQTT.ClientImpl._disconnected @ mqttws31.js:1459

Paho.MQTT.ClientImpl._on_socket_error @ mqttws31.js:1347

(anonymous) @ mqttws31.js:157

i tried to change the ports but i got the same problem.
how can i fix something like that ?
and if i tried to connect to https://test.mosquitto.org/
i got the same problem ? how can this be fixed too ?

Comment: Please post text of errors rather than images then the information shows up in searched

Comment: What happens if you change the clientid to a random string?

Comment: i edited my post and added text of errors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the flag to enable SSL (as the picture of the ports suggests TLS is required for Websockets)

```
var options = {
  timeout: 3,
  onSuccess: onConnect,
  useSSL: true
};
```

Comment: i have done this , i got now no error message . but my console just stuck at this (connecting to m23.cloudmqtt.com 38788)  . and when i checked my cloudmqtt server log i found those messages 
2018-03-01 17:42:26: Socket error on client <unknown>, disconnecting.
2018-03-01 17:42:26: Socket error on client <unknown>, disconnecting.
2018-03-01 17:43:11: Socket error on client <unknown>, disconnecting.
2018-03-01 17:43:12: Socket error on client <unknown>, disconnecting.
2018-03-01 17:45:29: Socket error on client <unknown>, disconnecting.)

Comment: it works after i added useSSL: true , it was my mistake that i didnt add username & password at var options

Comment: @hardillb ...you are such a boss of mqtt...lol...i see all mqtt questions answered by you

Answer (score 0):

please check this code:

change websocket and port and user and password , get from cloudmqtt.com

```html
<html>

<head>

  <title>My First Value</title>


<h1>Main Body</h1>



<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/paho-mqtt/1.0.1/mqttws31.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

 </head>


<body>


<h1><div id="connstatus">
Mqtt Not connected.</div></h1>
</body>

<script>

var websocket="m13.cloudmqtt.com";
var port=31609;
var user="test1234";
var pass="test1234";

 //client = new Paho.MQTT.Client(websocket, port, "web_" + parseInt(Math.random() * 100, 10));

client = new Paho.MQTT.Client(websocket, port, "Deviceid_34534543");


  // set callback handlers
  client.onConnectionLost = onConnectionLost;
  client.onMessageArrived = onMessageArrived;

  var options = {
    useSSL: true,
    userName: user,
    password: pass,
    onSuccess:onConnect,
    onFailure:doFail
  }

  // connect the client

    client.connect(options);


  // called when the client connects

  function onConnect() {
    // Once a connection has been made, make a subscription and send a message.


document.getElementById("connstatus").innerHTML = "Mqtt Connected";

  console.log("Mqtt Connected");

        client.subscribe("/sensor/#");
        message = new Paho.MQTT.Message("Hello world");
        message.destinationName = "/sensor/1";
        client.send(message);
      

  }

  function doFail(e){
    console.log(e);
  }

  // called when the client loses its connection
  function onConnectionLost(responseObject) {

    document.getElementById("connstatus").innerHTML = "Mqtt Not Connected";

    if (responseObject.errorCode !== 0) {
      console.log("onConnectionLost:"+responseObject.errorMessage);
    }
  }

function onMessageArrived(message) {

console.log("onMessageArrived:"+message.destinationName);
console.log("message.payloadString:"+message.payloadString);

 
  
}


</script>

</html>
```